# Bind mongodb to spring application on bluemix

Tags: spring, mongodb, ibm-cloud

I deployed a Spring application to Bluemix and now I need to bind a mongoDB.
I want to use Mongolab database, since the Mongolab service is no longer available on bluemix how can I bind my application to my database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternatively use [MongoDB by Compose](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/mongodb-by-compose/). It is an IBM provided service, and it allows you to get quick support using :

- the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, select the type of assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Answer (score 0):

To request a new service instance, you must use the Bluemix user interface or the cf command line interface.

If you want to use command line:

```
 cf create-service service_name service_plan service_instance
```

You can see all services and plans typing:

```
cf marketplace
```

and see the following command to bind the service instance to an application, where appname is the name of the application, and service_instance is the name of the service instance.

```
 cf bind-service appname service_instance
```

more information here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/reqnsi.html#req_instance

Comment: Mongo lab Service It is no longer available even using CLI.

Comment: You can use one of these options:
* MongoLab. You may continue to work with MongoLab by creating an account directly with MongoLab. (https://mongolab.com/)
* IBM MongoDB by Compose. At the current time, users will need to create an account at Compose.io.  Full integration into Bluemix will complete in the near future.